Is it possible to use NavDeepLinkBuilder to build a explicit deep link based on serializable route?
The current NavDeepLinkBuilder seemingly only supports setDestination(id: int) or setDestination(id: String). I'm using navigationCompose = "2.8.0".
I tried to use MyRoute::class.serializer().generateHashCode() as an interger input, but it didn't work.
